# How does one remove from Edit text so that they won't have to press enter in order for it to accept a string

Tags: android

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            word=edit.getText().toString();
            word=word.toUpperCase();
            Log.d("word1",word);
            Log.d( "User set EditText value to " ,word);
        }
    });
```

It only works if they press enter is their a way for it just to get the string while they type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a TextWatcher.  However, you'll never know they're done entering text until they hit enter, or some other button.  This will update you character by character.